# Is there a way to deserialize a json response that has a dynamic name into C# class?

Tags: c#, regex, json, deserialization

I'm calling an API that returns the json data with a dynamic property name, I'm trying to build a class that I can deserialize this response into, but this property name is a pain in my butt.

```
"data": {
  "1": {
    "Item": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Item 1"
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "Item": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Item 2"
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "Item": {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Item 3"
```

What's the best way to deal with this scenario? I'm trying to come up with a regex that I can use to remove the outer node but no success yet.

Any help?

Comment: What is the dynamic property name??

Comment: There is no name on it. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "1" and "2" are the dynamic property names, what about just making "data" into a Dictionary instead of trying to manipulate the response with RegEx? You can simply enumerate through the dictionary after that.

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, ItemContainer> { get; set; }
}

public class ItemContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("Item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The dictionary is missing a property name, so I added "items" to it.

I also implemented it and now the "items" inside the response are null after doing the following:

 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponseForGetAllItems>(response.Content);

Any ideas?

Comment: I did it wrong, after taking a closer look at your code I moved some stuff around and it worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

this should strip it.  It finds the first occurance of { and goes from there so the result string will be {......} instead of "varname": {......}

```
myjson = jsonstring.Substring (jsonstring.IndexOf('{'));
```